# Return single object instead of IEnumerable

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

Please see the line of code below:

```
Dim bookDetails = context.BookEntities.Where(Function(b) b.ISBN = ISBN)
```

bookDetails is populated with IEnumerable(Of Book).  How can I populate bookDetails with a single book i.e. the ISBN is unique so will always return one row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Where` method filters a collection and produces a filtered collection.  Other methods filter a collection and produce a single matching result, such as:

- Single
- SingleOrDefault
- First
- FirstOrDefault
- Last
- LastOrDefault

In the case of the `OrDefault` methods, they will return the matched element or the default instance for that type (`null` for reference types).  The other methods will throw an exception if no match is found.

For example, if you want the *only* instance which matches your predicate, and an error if there is no match (or if there is more than one match), use:

```
Dim bookDetails = context.BookEntities.Single(Function(b) b.ISBN = ISBN)
```

If you want a `null` value instead of an error:

```
Dim bookDetails = context.BookEntities.SingleOrDefault(Function(b) b.ISBN = ISBN)
```

If there can be more than one, and you want the first instance:

```
Dim bookDetails = context.BookEntities.First(Function(b) b.ISBN = ISBN)
```

And so on...

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
Dim bookDetails = context.BookEntities.Where(Function(b) b.ISBN = ISBN).SingleOrDefault ()
```

It will either return a single object or NULL/default if there is no match.  More than one will result in an error.  If you use .Single() then it'll throw an error if there is more than one result or no results.

Comment: SingleOrDefault will return null if there's 0 elements; but will throw if there's > 1. Single will throw if there's 0 elements or > 1.

Comment: I was always under the impression that single or default would return NULL if >1.  You learn something new every day!

Answer (score 1):

Be explicit, and just call for [`.Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535118%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (or [`.SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if the ISBN may not exist).

```
Dim bookDetails = context.BookEntities.Single(Function(b) b.ISBN = ISBN)
```